# How to solve this numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have this system of differential equation.

$my''+bx'=f$      ... (A)
$bx'=k(y-x)$      ... (B)

From (B), (A) is

$my''+k(y-x)=f$        ... (C)

For simplicity, $f=0$ .

To solve this numercially, I did this.
By (C), $y$'s value at next time step can calculated by
current time step value of $y$ and $x$ .
Similarly, by (B), $x$'s value at next time step can calculated by
current value of $y$ and $x$ .
Then I did leap frog and calculated time response of $x$ and $y$ .
However, the result diverged.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action is to reduce to a system of first order differential equations and use a standard ode solver on that system.

$$
\begin{cases}
y' = z\\ 
z' = -\frac{k}{m} (y-x) +\frac fm \\ x' = \frac kb (y-x) 
\end{cases}
$$

Edit:
With the set of parameters given in the comments below, Wolfram returns a numerical solution with a maximum error in the order of $10^{-8}$. The error is measured with respect to the analytical solution.

Comment: Thank you. but it still diverges.  I used forward difference Euler method.

Comment: @ShuS can you tell what is the precise set of parameters that you are using? $k,m,b$, time interval and initial conditions? How is it diverging? Some solutions may have exponential growth... Anyway, forward Euler is not very accurate and may require very small time steps. Since this is a linear equation you may even try to solve it exactly.

Comment: I used $k = 100000.0$ , $m = 1.0$ , $b = 0.01$, time interval is $1/4800000$ seconds, and initial condition is {$x,y,z$} = { $0, 0, 0.1$} .   it is oscillating and growing exponentially. This system is mass-damper-spring system, in terms of equivalent circuit, C and R is parallel , and L is series. So solution may be decaying oscillation.   "solve it exactly" means "analytically" ?

Comment: @ShuS is 1/480000 the time interval (full time frame) or the time step? And yes, when you have a system of linear differential equations you can normally get a closed form solution. It is all about computing a matrix exponential.

Comment: Sorry, 1/4800000 is the time step, and time interval is 3.0 seconds. I want to get numerical solution, and I want to know why it diverges.

Comment: @ShuS wolfram returns the numerical solution with no problem whatsoever... Maybe you need to use a more accurate ode solver to avoid using such small time steps...